# WinError 5 - Access is denied while executing command python setup.py egg_info installing bitcoinlib (Repost)

Tags: python

Error:

```
pip install bitcoinlib: ERROR: Error [WinError 5] Access is denied while executing command python setup.py egg_info
error
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
Check the permissions.
```

And just so everyone knows, it gets up to:

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ...
```

But then spits out the error. And yes, I tried running the `pip install bitcoinlib as administator`,  and with `--user`. Is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: Run the IDE as admin or the PowerShell window as admin then try

Comment: I have tried that already.